# HTML keystroke goes to home page

Tags: keyboard, key, html

What would the code look like for html for which when someone is anywhere on the site, if they press the key "ESC", it will send them to the home page of the site?

Comment: First create a key press listener, and then change the `location` of the window when it fires.  You'll also have to check which key is pressed.  Do you have any code you have already tried?  It's best to provide that information in your initial question.

Comment: Nope no code, just based on theory to prove a friend wrong. He doesn't think it could be done. With my experience in Java, it would be fairly easy. I figured it would be just as easy in HTML

Comment: Strictly speaking it's not possible in HTML.  That kind of interaction requires javascript; however, it is pretty easy to do in javascript.  Would that work still?  Javascript is not java, but I'm not sure if that's exactly what you were after.

Comment: Javascript is possible in a few ways. I would use element.addEventListener(event, function, useCapture);
But I was discussing with him a way to do it exclusively in HTML.